# Writing a WebDAV Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, webdav

I am going to write a webDAV server hosting in IIS with ASP.NET. I think I have to write a new one because I have to integrate it with our custom security module. Actually I think I have to  check some security (membership and roles) concerns on webDAV file request and respond to request based on that security concerns.

How can I write a WebDAV server? Or are there any libraries suitable for me?

Comment: A good one but not free. http://www.webdavsystem.com/

Comment: this question is very broad for SO and is not about coding.  Try posting it on programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Regarding existing libraries - there exists a free webdav project on SourceForge, then there exist paid components on http://webdavsystem.com and we offer WebDAV server within our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-webdav.php) component suite. All of them can be integrated with IIS. Offered level of fine-tuning such as authentication control and filesystem access is of course different. Our SecureBlackbox is biased towards flexibility and feature-richness.